# insert image in html table from database

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to display my images in a HTML table but for some reason they just won't show up.

The images are located in a separate folder called 'images' and the image name is stored in my database as a varchar named e.g., filename.jpg

In my overview page I use this as my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <table>
    <?php
        foreach ($objectname as $key) {
            echo '<tr><td><img src="images/' . $key->getImage() . '"></td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hoping someone here can point me in the right direction :) thanks!!

Comment: Please show getIamge() function

Comment: public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

Comment: is the `image` directory a sub-directory of the current working directory or is it at root level?

Comment: if it is one image per table row why bother with the table at all?

Comment: it's not just the image. In the next cell, I'm showing a title and a year,... those all work fine, just couldn't understand why the images weren't showing up. but it works now!

Answer (score -1):

You should first print print_r ($objectname), check if it comes with data and what its attributes are to see which one you need to occupy.
Second the $ key->getImage() getImage () = function () you are calling a function.

Comment: thanks for this! think i see what went wrong... it's appointing the image name to the wrong attribute

Answer (score -2):

I think you should change the getImage() function in your html to the name of the field in the database as follows: 
**$key->getImage()** to **$key->Image_field_name_in_the_database**

Because the name of the image (e.g: filename.jpg) is saved in a field of a table in your database.
**Image_field_name_in_the_database** will be the name of the field that contains the name of the image in the database.

Comment: Hello Dadinaks, welcome to SO.  As a friendly suggestion, you might consider editing your answer and explain a little more why you feel like this is a valid solution based on the information provided.

Comment: ah okay, thanks for your help, I appreciate it. 
actually I didn't quite understand his post and where his getImage() function comes from so I thought of php mysql on the data collection from the database.